# Can my computer handle Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hardware

I was wondering... Can I run Ubuntu with these specs?

- Windows XP SP2 (x86)
- Compaq Presario
- AMD Anthlon 64
- Processor 3400+ 1.81 GHz
- 896 MB of RAM

Could I run Ubuntu alongside this computer without messing up the Windows operating system/BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

You can run Ubuntu, but you might find it to be a bit slow. You can try the lightweight  official variants [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) if you wish; they still have all the same available software and support.

Ubuntu will destroy the Windows boot sector and MBR - but nothing else, unless you tell it to during Setup - to install the [Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) bootloader. Grub will allow you to set up Ubuntu and Windows alongside each other in a [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) configuration, allowing you to choose between the two upon boot.

If you want to, you can try Ubuntu 12.04 with [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). This allows you to install Ubuntu as you would a program in Windows, making it easy to "Uninstall", just as you would any other Windows program, from the Control Panel. This, however, doesn't work with the latest and (some say) greatest version of Ubuntu, 13.04.

Comment: With 896 MB RAM i don't think it would be wise to use the 64-bit version.

Comment: ... True. Will edit.